# How do I use graphics functions in CUDA?

Tags: c, cuda, bgi

I want to use basic functions like putpixel, initwindow in CUDA. How do I do it?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough, what do you mean by "in CUDA"? Calling those functions from the device? Not possible. Calling them on the host to e.g. visualize results from CUDA? Certainly possible.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to CUDA. I think I want to visualise results from CUDA, i.e call them on Host.

Comment: There is opengl - opencl buffer sharing under interop context. Same should be in cuda since a lot of raytracers and fluid simulations run hundreds of fps in cuda too. But you can try text-based "simulation"  of pixels like old dnd games.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use the CUDA - OpenGL interop to visualize results from CUDA, see e.g. http://3dgep.com/opengl-interoperability-with-cuda/

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. It involves code for implementation. However, I am facing problem in creating the program itself. The instructions to run an openGL program in Microsoft Visual Studio can't be found at all. Where can I find this information? I am a complete beginner in this field.

Comment: How about [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=opengl+visual+studio)? First result is this link for me: http://in2gpu.com/2014/10/15/setting-up-opengl-with-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

CUDA cannot output directly to a window backbuffer. However, you can still use CUDA to write to a texture or a buffer and then use the results to visualize it in OpenGL.
For a thorough example on how to do this, please refer to this project:

https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_cuda_interop_pingpong_st